# How to insert complex XML into MYSQL database?

Tags: mysql, xml, import

I am attempting to use MYSQL 5.5 XML features to import data from several XML files.  I'm having an issue getting the data in exactly how I need it.  Can someone help?  Here's an example of the XML files I'm trying to import:

XML File 1

```
<event where="work" meeting="001" year="2013">'
  <category>feedback</category>
  <summary>Improve dataflow capability</summary>
  <option key="+">Yes</option>
  <option key="-">No</option>
  <employee vote="+" employee="mike" id="00001" value="Yes"/>
  <employee vote="+" employee="sarah" id="00002" value="Yes"/>
  <employee vote="-" employee="myles" id="00003" value="No"/>
</event>
```

XML File 2

```
<event where="roll" meeting="001" year="2013">
  <category>attendance</category>
  <summary>persons participating</summary>
  <option key="+">Yes</option>
  <option key="-">No</option>
  <employee vote="+" employee="mike" id="00001" value="Yes"/>
  <employee vote="+" employee="sarah" id="00002" value="Yes"/>
  <employee vote="+" employee="myles" id="00003" value="Yes"/>
</event>'
```

I've attempted to use the LOAD XML INFILE feature:

```
USE meetings;
LOAD XML INFILE '/var/www/data/data.xml'
INTO TABLE record
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<event>';
```

I would like to have each event have it's own row but with the multiple employees loaded into a single MYSQL column (maybe comma separated?).  Any help would be much appreciated!